# Customize shell scripts based on environment like development test staging production

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to customize my shell scripts. I have some environment/properties files in my work space where the shell scripts will have to pick up the respective variables during installation based on the environment.

Ex: if the variables in the properties file is defined as below:

```
com.prod.filename=PRODFILE
com.test.filename=TESTFILE
com.dev.filename=DEVFILE
```

And when I am installing any project or during run-time based on the environment it has to pick up the right file required. That is if the environment is test, then it has to pick TESTFILE.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your property files should all follow the same naming convention.

e.g.

```
myapp/properties/dev.properties
myapp/properties/qa.properties
myapp/properties/prod.properties
```

Your shell script(s), should determine which property file to use based on an environment variable e.g. `APP_ENV`, which defaults to `dev`. For example:

**startApp.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
APP_ENV=${APP_ENV:-dev}
PROPERTIES_FILE=myapp/properties/${APP_ENV}.properties

# run the command using the properties file
echo "Using: ${PROPERTIES_FILE}"
mycommand ${PROPERTIES_FILE}
```

You can run your application for different environments by changing the `APP_ENV` variable. For example, to run in `prod`:

```
$ APP_ENV=prod startApp.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an [associative array](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) and associate the file names with the respective environment name:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A filename
filename[prod]=PRODFILE
filename[test]=TESTFILE
filename[dev]=DEVFILE

environ=test
echo "${filename[$environ]}"
```

Output:

```
TESTFILE
```